# How to remove anything before and after two matching patterns in R

Tags: r, regex

I have this vector `myvec <- c( "tes_1123_SS1G_340TX1", "tes_23_SS2G_340TX21")`. I want to remove anything before SS and anything after TX and get the result: `SS1G_340TX`, `SS2G_340TX`.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this in one line. Here's one:

```
gsub(".*(SS.*TX).*","\\1",myvec)

[1] "SS1G_340TX" "SS2G_340TX"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the string from 'SS' and end at 'TX'

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(myvec, "SS.*TX")
#[1] "SS1G_340TX" "SS2G_340TX"
```

---

Or with `base R` using `regmatches/regexpr`

```
regmatches(myvec, regexpr("SS.*TX", myvec))
#[1] "SS1G_340TX" "SS2G_340TX"
```

Comment: If I have to exclude TX (i.e also remove TX), how could I do this?

Comment: @MAPK Perhaps `str_extract(myvec, "SS[^TX]*")` or with `sub(".*(SS.*)TX.*", "\\1", myvec)`